# Programmatically checkout webpage sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, checkout

Im trying to remove all content in page. but i get an exception when i trying to do this, it says that the file is not checked out and i have to do this. And when i use `file.CheckOut()` I see that the file is checked out to the systemAccount and i get exception:

> The file is CheckedOut to another user

How to do that i can ignore the CheckOut to the current/specific user

this is what i have tried

```
 SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
{
   var webMngr = web.GetLimitedWebPartManager("Sidor/default.aspx", PersonalizationScope.Shared);
    List<System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPart> webPartList = (from     System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPart webPart in webMngr.WebParts select webPart).ToList();
SPFile file = web.GetFile(web.Url+"Sidor/default.aspx");

web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
if (file.CheckOutType == SPFile.SPCheckOutType.Online)
{

    file.CheckIn("Comment");
}  
file.CheckOut();

object _lock = new object();

lock (_lock)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < webMngr.WebParts.Count; i++)
    {
        webMngr.DeleteWebPart(webPartList[i]);
    }
}
web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  file.forceCheckOut = false
```

here the msdn function
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.forcecheckout(v=office.15).aspx